# Collection iteration in javascript using inline server tags

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net user control which exposes a public IEnumerable object. This could be converted to a list or array if it helps to answer the question. What I would like to do is to loop through all of the server objects within a javascript function and do something with the contents of each item. I would like to achieve this using inline server tags if possible. Something like the below.

```
function iterateServerCollection()
{
    foreach(<%=PublicCollection %>)
    {
        var somevalue = <%=PublicCollection.Current.SomeValue %>;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: One way would be to serialise your .NET collection to a client side javascript array (have a look at JavaScriptSerializer class in System.Web.Script.Serialization) and then loop through that in javascript on the client side. You would also want to use a for loop in javascript

Comment: It is not possible for client side javascript to iterate over server side asp.net objects.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Managed to do what I wanted using JavaScriptSerializer. Thanks geedubb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to achieve what I wanted thanks to the comment from geedubb. Here's what the working javascript looks like.

```
var myCollection = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myCollection) %>;

for(var i in myCollection)
{
    var somevalue = myCollection[i].SomeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as others have suggested and serialize the object, you could even use an ajax call to grab the data from the start of that function

```
function iterateServerCollection()
{

    //Ajax call to get data from server HttpHandler/WebAPI/Service etc.

    for(var item in resultObject) {
        //you can use item.WhateverPropertyIsOnObject
    }
}
```